# Making personal profile after Devise / Omniauth-facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, profile, omniauth-facebook

I'm relatively new to the RoR community and I'm trying to make a personal profile for each users after their authentications through the original Devise or Omniauth-Facebook. I am sort of stuck on where to go after implementing authentications systems.

I was hoping some of you could give me a slight lead and some push after signup/signin redirect to a personal page showing name of the logged in user. I've tried creating new models for profile and views but with no luck.

My ultimate goal is to have each user's profile page show name, picture and some text that user had uploaded...

Here are my lines of code:

user.rb User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true ) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def email_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end
end
```

class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

```
if user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect user, notice: "Signed in!"
else
  session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" } 
  root            'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' =>   'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' =>  'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

finally gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby   '2.1.4'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0.beta4'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer',    '1.0.1'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

Do I need to do rails generate devise:controllers to customize redirects upon signin/signup ?
Or is it possible to make separate controller and model to manage all that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One option could be after successful sign up redirect to the profile page where you would have a view based upon what info the user has supplied, so on the first occasion there would be nothing, so have a button ready called 'Create profile', they click that and then create their profile, upon their return to the profile page they would have their info there

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that is where I am having issues. Redirect after signin only seems to take me to the root page... is that a problem with routes or the controller redirects?

Comment: if you look in the documentation you will find the answer to this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29